# Virtual Memory Organization

Tags: memory, virtual-memory, computer-architecture

I have a question pertaining to virtual memory.  In the description we always tend to show Heap growing from Low Address to High Address, and Stack in the other direction e.g.

[image]

---

**Question:** Is this just a convention, or is there some logic behind it?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old diagram that does not exist in reality; that has not existed
since segmented and paged memory was introduced.

The stack and the heap and the code are allocated as separate memory
segments, so they can never meet and can never have overlapping
areas. Each can increase or decrease in size to the limits of one
segment size (which is very considerable in 64-bit), and even then
multiple segments can be employed (especially for the heap that doesn't
even need to be allocated sequentially).
No meaningful order can be attributed to the segments, each can be
anywhere in the physical memory; pages that are consecutive in
logical address do not need to be consecutive in physical memory (see
paging tables).

Perhaps this is best illustrated by this image from
[Wikipedia Virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how some operating systems arrange the virtual memory of a process.

On Unix, one way of updating the used amount of memory is the `sbrk` system call which tell how much memory it uses. This means all the memory excepted the stack is allocated like this. The stack typically grow on the other way, but this way is implied by the CPU (and its push/pop/call/return operations).

But with dynamic libraries, code and data can be interleaved. Some systems also put libraries randomly in the memory to prevent some attacks. (Using a buffer overflow vulnerability can be harder if the interesting addresses to patch/jump are set ramdomly).

Note that Unix systems has the `sbrk` syscall, but can also allocate memory with `mmap` which can allocate memory at any location in the middle.  See https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/malloc/malloc.c (a Gnu/Linux malloc with its `mmap` call at line 2313)

Answer (score 0):

The logic is that, unless your program is trivial, the compiler doesn't really know how much memory the heap needs and how much the stack needs, so it starts one of them at one end of memory and the other at the other end, and it's up to the programmer to make sure they don't run into each other.

This is how things worked before multitasking and virtual memory. As other answers have indicated, operating systems that support those features (including virtually all modern desktop PCs, servers, and mobile devices) map the heap and the stack into virtual memory segments that are managed by the operating system and do not overlap.

The model of a heap and a stack existing in the same physical memory is, however, still relevant to many embedded systems like IoT appliances.